# Questions on the type of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have a function

```
void function(double p[2]) {
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << endl;
}
```

If I try that following code

```
double a[1] = {1};
double b[2] = {2, 3};
double c[3] = {4, 5, 6};
function(a);
function(b);
function(c);
```

I get something like

```
1 2.0778e-317
2 3
4 5
```

In other words, the `2` seems to get completely ignored and all 3 arrays get passed to the function anyway.

Are the following exactly the same?

```
void function(double p[2])
void function(double p[])
void function(double *p)
```

If they are, is there any way to make a function that will only accept an array of a particular length or of at least a particular length? The reason I ask is that the types of `a`, `b` and `c` appear to be different. (You get different results for `typeid(a).name()` and `typeid(b).name()` for example).

Comment: To avoid decay you can get a reference to an array or a pointer to an array, but those are weird in C++: `void function(double (&p)[2])`, `void function(double (*p)[2])`.

Comment: @rodrigo How would I call those functions using `b`?

Comment: The reference one would be just `function(b)` and the pointer one `function(&b)`. But if you want to pass the 2 first values of `c` as argument (that a seasoned C++ developer will want to be able to do), you'll have to do some nasty casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same. An array function parameter gets *adjusted* to pointer. All information to do with array length is lost.

If you'd attempted to define these three functions, you would get multiple definition errors:

```
void function(double p[2]) {} // defines void function(double*)
void function(double p[]) {}  // ERROR
void function(double *p) {}   // ERROR
```

This confusing feature of the language is inherited from C.

To enforce that a function only accepts array arguments of a certain type, you can use a reference to array:

```
void function(const double(&p)[2]);
```

Note that *parameter adjustment* is not the same as array *decay*. Array decay is what happens when you call `function` with an array's name as argument, or when you simply assign an array to a pointer.

```
double a[42] = {};
function(a);    // a decays to double*
double * b = a; // a decays to double*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the fact that you get different results for `typeid(a).name()` etc does not mean that there is any way to declare a variable or parameter to be of type `A2_d` for example?

Comment: @PaulBoddington That's right. In fact, I admit to being surprised that this produces different type IDs.

Comment: You can declare a reference to an array, which does preserve the size information.

Comment: @n.m. Right. Or I would say it *enforces* that the argument be an array of a particular type (which can be of course by deduced in a function template.)